# Why Is The Selected Value Different Between Using Route ID and Action Parameter in SelectList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, selectlist

I have a SelectList in my action method. The selected value for SelectList is coming from the action method parameter. The action and view are simple like below:

```
// Recipe Action
 public ActionResult Recipe(int? recipeId)
 {
     ViewBag.RecipeID = new SelectList(_recipsRecipes, "RecipeID", "RecipeName", recipeId);
     return View(new Recipe());
 }

//Recipe View
 @model RecipeDemo.Models.Recipe

 @Html.DropDownList("RecipeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.RecipeID, string.Empty)
```

I'm using ActionLink below to call the Recipe action.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Recipe", "Recipe", "Home", new { recipeId = 2 }, null)
```

It works like I expect, the DropDownList is showing the selected value as the No. 2 (recipeId = 2) item.

**Problem**

When I change the Recipe action parameter by using route id, like below:

```
//Recipe View 
public ActionResult Recipe(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.RecipeID = new SelectList(_recipsRecipes, "RecipeID", "RecipeName", id);
    return View(new Recipe());
}

//Recipe View (Same View as above)
@model RecipeDemo.Models.Recipe

@Html.DropDownList("RecipeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.RecipeID, string.Empty)
```

And I'm using ActionLink below to call the Recipe action.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Recipe", "Recipe", "Home", new { id = 2 }, null)
```

The DropDownList is **NOT** showing the selected value, (id = 2) item. The selection is instead empty.
But I have the correct id value in the SelectList. see below:

[image]

Why is this, does anyone know the explanation?

**Update**:

The model is below:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does `the selection is instead empty` mean? There are no values in the drop down list or nothing is selected? If you debug, is `_recipsRecipes` still the same as before?

Comment: Nothing is selected in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Interesting test comes to mind, if you change the name of your dropdownlist in example 1, does it fail like example 2?  Meaning - use this in the first example - @Html.DropDownList("FakeRecipeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.RecipeID, string.Empty)

Comment: hi @Tommy, I tried it, the first one still works.

Comment: How complex is the Recipe() class?  Can you post it here?

Comment: @Tommy, I updated the question, it's a really simple model class.

Comment: @Lin - I just wanted to see that to reproduce your issue and work it out.  Answer below, let me know if that all made some sense.

Comment: @Lin - and added an alternative with better/clearer explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was certainly interesting.  After first confirming the issue with the code you provided, I experimented around and believe I have the root cause.  Basically, you are using the same variable name way to often and the model binder appears to be getting confused.  You have `RecipeId` in your route, `RecipeId` in your View Model and `RecipeId` as the name of your view bag variable. By altering my variable names, the `SelectList` works as expected.

The primary issue is naming your SelectList `RecipeId` which matches a property in your model.  When you send the new Recipe(), the model binder is attempting to use that value.  In your first example, since you have `RecipeId` defined in the URL, it is getting it from there.  In the second example, there is no `RecipeId` to pull from the URL and it is null in the model.

**Controller**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private List<Recipe> Recipes;

        public HomeController()
        {
            Recipes = new List<Recipe>
                {
                    new Recipe {RecipeId = 1, RecipeName = "Test - 1"},
                    new Recipe {RecipeId = 2, RecipeName = "Test - 2"},
                    new Recipe {RecipeId = 3, RecipeName = "Test - 3"},
                };
        }

        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            ViewBag.MyList = new SelectList(Recipes, "RecipeID", "RecipeName", id);
            return View(new Recipe());
        }
    }
}
```

**Index View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Recipe

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

 @Html.DropDownList("MyRecipeId", (SelectList)ViewBag.MyList)
```

Basically, vary your parameter names a little bit more to help prevent the model binder from getting confused and/or pulling information from the wrong place.

You can verify this in your second example by sending this in your return statement:

```
Return View(New Recipe{RecipeId = 3});
```

The option value with 3 will be selected regardless of what the actual Id sent was.

**EDIT**

An even better option would be to do what I said to do as an example above.  By changing your Action to this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
  {
    ViewBag.MyList = new SelectList(Recipes, "RecipeID", "RecipeName");
    return View(new Recipe(RecipeId = id));
   }
```

You can leave your view unchanged.  Now, the SelectList will pull from the model that you are sending.

Comment: hi @Tommy, your explanation does make sense. It never occurred to me that this was the problem. Thanks a lot.